# User Not Found when using AddUserToRole

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, asp.net-4.5, role-manager

I'm trying to assign user to a role in asp.net membership.

```
protected void btnAssignUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole("Upendra", "Admin"); 
        }
```

but I'm keep getting the error below.

> The user 'Upendra' was not found.

However, 'Upendra' user does does exists in the Users table and also the 'Admin' role in the Roles table.

My web.config settings are as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=IROSHEN-PC;Initial Catalog=IndunilaDB;Integrated Security=true;" />

  </connectionStrings>
      <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </profile>
        <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPXROLES"
    cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
    cookieProtection="All" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" createPersistentCookie="false"
    maxCachedResults="25">
          <providers>
            <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="IndunillaWeb" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
```

Comment: The problem occurs on any existant user you want to add to that role?

Comment: Did you try the solution I provided in my below answer? Is your problem solved?

Comment: is this issue solved..if so please post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below method and see if this helps. At least you will know what exactly going on with Provider:

```
    public void AssignUserToRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        if (Roles.RoleExists(roleName))
        {
            string[] rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
            if (rolesArray.Length > 0)
            {
                // One user should be in one role so remove previous role
                Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(username, rolesArray);
            }
            Roles.AddUserToRole(username, roleName);
        }
        else
            // RoleName does not exist, You may want to handle this case.
            // May just add the role and call this method again or throw...
    }
```